# Difficult to grasp the scala template in play 2.0

Tags: frameworks, playframework-2.0

I have earlier worked with play 1.2.4 and found the groovy template quite easier as compared to scala template in play 2.0. I have gone through the documentation of play 2.0. It seems that I should have some initial knowledge in scala. Please help me out or suggest me some tutorial to grasp a good knowledge in scala templates so that i can play with play 2.0....

Answer (score 1):

Start with a beginner tutorial like [this one](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/firstapp)

The [playframework website- template section](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaTemplates) is a good next section to explore. You wont find everything you need on there but its got the nittygritties to templating.
You might also want to look into the basics of Scala syntax, [this](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.ca/2008/09/scala-syntax-primer.html) is a good tutorial

From there on you should have foundations and if you run into further obstacles I'm sure you can figure them out via trial and error or through asking more specific questions

Good luck